# How and where can i use map along with list/set collection to get unique output

Tags: apex, trigger, list, map, set

When I enter `united states` I need only one language. If I selected wrong language it want to throw an error.

```
    Map<String,String> countryMap = new Map<String,String>();
       countryMap.put('Germany','German');
       countryMap.put('Spain','Spanish');
       countryMap.put('France' ,'French');
       countryMap.put('UnitedStates','English');
       countryMap.put('UnitedStates','Spanish');
       countryMap.put('Canada','French');
       countryMap.put('Canada','English');
        for(String c : newCountries){
            for(String l : newLanguages){
                if(!Countrymap.get(c).contains(l)){
                    error = true;
                    account.adderror( 'country ' + c + ' does not support language ' + l);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you just need a space between `United` and `States`?  Looks like a typo

Comment: If you need only one language per country, why do you try to insert more than one, like you did for 'UnitedStates'?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a double For loop and you should avoid that pattern, it is very inefficient.

A Map is a (key, value) set so you can only hold 1 Country to 1 Language pair, the 2nd UnitedStates pair (UnitedStates, Spanish) replaces the first (UnitedStates, English).

Generally with a map you will want to iterate through a list of keys(Countries) and get the values (Language) to compare.

There is no map.contains() in Apex but there is countryMap.containsKey().

Comment: Do you mind showing a code sample of how this could work?  Also consider the fact that `Set<String>` does have a `.contains()` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample if you want to iterate through the Map to look for a specific value:

```
for(String c : newCountries){
  if(c == 'United States' && Countrymap.get(c) != 'English'){
    //Throw error because language is not English
  }
}
```

As @BrianMiller mentioned there is a .contains() method on Set so here is a code sample if you want to create a unique Set of values and see if it already exists:

```
Set uniqueLanguages = new Set();
for(String c : newCountries){
   if(!uniqueLanguages.contains(Countrymap.get(c)){
      uniqueLanguages.add(Countrymap.get(c));
   }
   else{
      //Throw error because this is a duplicate language
   }
}
```